# OpenERP - Odoo - How to have the percentage of quote that become a sale orders

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

Is it possible to have easily the percentage of sales orders / quotes per users?

The objective it is to know what the percentage of quote that become a sale order per user.

I have not a clue how I can do it.
I am using OpenERP 7

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible by using status bar.
In order for you to compute the percentage of sales order, you should determine how much is the quota for each sale order.

Comment: What do you mean by status bar? Is it possible to have like a graph with the number of quote and number of sale order per user?